# TApplicationEvents.OnMessage does not capture the WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE message

Tags: delphi, clipboard, delphi-11-alexandria

To be notified when the clipboard content changes in Windows 10, I usually use a `TApplicationEvents` component with this code:

```
procedure TformMain.AppEventsMainMessage(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  case Msg.message of
    Winapi.Messages.WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
      begin
        CodeSite.Send('TformMain.AppEventsMainMessage: WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE');
      end;
  end;
end;
```

And usually, it works. So I used this code also in an existing large project. But there, the `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE` message is not fired in the `TApplicationEvents.OnMessage` event handler!

What could prevent this message from being captured in the `TApplicationEvents.OnMessage` event handler?

EDIT: ONLY when using the `AddClipboardFormatListener` function, that DOES work in my project:

```
procedure TformMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Winapi.Windows.AddClipboardFormatListener(Handle);

procedure TformMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Winapi.Windows.RemoveClipboardFormatListener(Handle);

Private
  procedure WMClipboardUpdate(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE;

implementation

  procedure TformMain.WMClipboardUpdate(var Msg: TMessage);
  begin
    CodeSite.Send('TformMain.WMClipboardUpdate: WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE');
  end;
```

But this does not answer the question "What could prevent this message from being captured in the `TApplicationEvents.OnMessage` event handler?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows doesn't broadcast `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE` to all windows when the clipboard is updated. Instead, you have to register your window if you want to be notified. From the documentation of [`AddClipboardFormatListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-addclipboardformatlistener):

> Places the given window in the system-maintained clipboard format listener list.
>
> When a window has been added to the clipboard format listener list, it is posted a `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE` message whenever the contents of the clipboard have changed.

So after you have called

```
AddClipboardFormatListener(Handle)
```

the window with HWND `Handle` will be posted `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE` messages when the clipboard is changed. If you write

```
AddClipboardFormatListener(Handle)
```

in your `TformMain.FormCreate`, then `Handle` means `Self.Handle`, that is, the window associated with `TformMain` will be posted the messages. So they can be detected by your `TformMain`'s

```
procedure WMClipboardUpdate(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE;
```

But if you have a second form, `TformSecond`, it will not receive any such messages, because you did only register your `TformMain`.

Also, any message *posted* to a window in your application will pass through your `TApplicationEvents`. This means that if you have registered *any* window in your app using `AddClipboardFormatListener`, then any `TApplicationEvents` in your app will see this message.

Comment: You were faster than me: I just discovered the same truth.

Comment: Andreas, thanks for your accurate and extensive explanation!

Comment: Would you agree that this would be a useful suggestion?: Add the event `OnClipboardChanged` to the `TApplicationEvents` class. That would prevent the user from having to manually add and remove the `ClipboardFormatListener`.

Comment: Sure, you could make that suggestion to Embarcadero.

Comment: Done: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-38670

Comment: I seriously doubt that Embarcadero will consider adding this, as most apps are simply not interested in monitoring the clipboard, and for those app that are, calling `AddClipboardFormatListener()` directly is trivial and not worth wrapping. Also, just FYI, the Form's `OnCreate` event is not the best place to call `AddClipboardFormatListener()`, it should be in the Form's overriden `CreateWnd()` or `CreateWindowHandle()` method instead, in case the Form's `HWND` gets recreated at rutnime (which *can* happen).

Comment: Yes, the point about CreateWnd is important.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Define "most apps".

Comment: @user1580348 do I really need to? When was the last time your web browser needed to do something if the clipboard was changed while viewing a website? Or your text editor while editing a document? Or your financial software while tracking transactions? Your spreadsheet? Your graphics editor? Your code editor? Windows Explorer? Email? Come on, think. *Monitoring* the clipboard for changes is a fairly specialized operation, MOST software don't care if it changes, they only care what is *currently* stored on it at the time they want to read from it during a paste operation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Just nitpicking: Most of these apps *do* need to be notified so they can update the state of the Paste menu item or button (enabled or disabled). Your main point is valid, though.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand From my experience, most apps that have a Paste item typically only query the current state of the clipboard at the time the Paste item is displayed to the user, they do not dynamically enable/disable the Paste item in real-time as the content of the clipboard is being updated while the Paste item's parent menu is active.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Andreas mentioned a Paste **BUTTON**. And that's exactly what I need it for: Enabling a PASTE BUTTON on the toolbar when the clipboard has specific content. And BTW, the clipboard is one of the most important data sources for ALL types of applications.

Comment: @user1580348 "*that's exactly what I need it for: Enabling a PASTE BUTTON on the toolbar when the clipboard has specific content*" - I would probably just assign a `TAction` to the button and use the `TAction.OnUpdate` event to query if the clipboard currently holds a type I want.

Comment: Yes, that is the standard way to do it in the VCL. `aPaste.Enabled := Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT)`, say.